# Do any damage resistances apply to Reverse Gravity?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage-resistance

I am under the impression that Reverse Gravity bypasses resistance to bludgeoning damage as the only ones I am aware of specify that it is bludgeoning damage **from weapons**.

**Are there any resistances possessed by monsters or granted by classes or feats, that could apply to the Reverse Gravity spell damage? If so, what are they?**

Comment: Since Reverse Gravity causes "falling damage", would your question better be reflected by addressing that in general instead of just this spell?

Comment: Not necessarily. Are there any abilities that grant a creature resistance to spell damage? That is a valuable distinction I believe.

Comment: Where does it say that Reverse Gravity bypasses resistance to Bludgeoning damage?

Comment: I don't think that the damage caused by Reverse Gravity counts as spell damage. The spell only states that "If some solid object is encountered in this fall, falling objects and creatures strike it just as they would during a normal downward fall", leading me to believe that this damage just counts as "falling damage"

Comment: @NautArch I don't know if the way I worded it is confusing, but with the exception of Netzach Sephira's answer of Barbarian Rage, every instance of resistance to Bludgeoning I can find specifically applies to _weapon damage_ only

Comment: [Resistance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#DamageResistanceandVulnerability) covers "If a creature or an object has resistance to a damage type, damage of that type is halved against it". That's it - anything that gives bludgeoning damage..

Comment: @Joshu'sMu Actually there is: Aura of Warding from the Paladin (Oath of the Ancients). The argument I would make for Reverse Gravity though is that the spell itself doesn't cause the damage, but that is me being nitpicky.

Comment: @Slagmoth To be honest, that's a question I would probably pose to some of the more official sources of D&D rulings. I think that's a valid point. Do we count the damage as occurring from the spell or from the fall? Is the fall magical because  spell caused it? I mean, you don't typically fall upwards... That would be a tough ruling for me, even as the DM.

Comment: @Joshu'sMu The spell does not list damage therefore it didn't cause any. If I banish you then dig a hole 30ft under the spot you left, is the resulting fall magical? I think not.

Comment: @Slagmoth I think your reasoning is correct. I will only point out that if you fail your save to Reverse Gravity, falling damage will definitely follow. Digging a hole while a creature is banished is two separate actions and obviously is a different scenario. Though I suppose I am nitpicking as a Gust of Wind could easily push someone over a cliff and cause non-magical falling damage.

Comment: Would it be better to separate this question into two questions: Is there any way to resist damage from falling? and: Does falling damage from Reverse Gravity count as spell damage?

Comment: If you are interested in a specific answer to the Reverse Gravity being magical damage part, then yes it wouldn't  hurt to do that.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose At this point I'm just interested in posing a better question. I want my question to be the most useful to anyone who has the same questions I do - I figure linking two different questions on the same line of reasoning would provide more robust answers to more questions...

Comment: @Joshu'sMu I think it would be good to do that then (as long as it hasn't already been asked).

Comment: You can ask it, but my answer does include that particular answer again.

Comment: @NautArch I think your answer answers two distinct questions. One of which is fairly basic so I didn't think to pose it separately until I saw the confusion that it caused...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Resistance to Bludgeoning is all that's required

[Resistance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#DamageResistanceandVulnerability) is active if a:

> ...creature or an object has resistance to a damage type,[then] damage of that type is halved against it.

In the case of [Reverse Gravity](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/reverse-gravity), the damage is described as (with my emphasis):

> If some solid object (such as a ceiling) is encountered in this fall, falling objects and creatures strike it **just as they would during a normal downward fall.**

Falling Damage is non-magical and therefore any and all sources of resistance to Bludgeoning damage are covered with this.

Some creatures may have a more specific resistance like "non-magical bludgeoning", but the umbrella "Bludgeoning" covers all sources.

### Some Sources of Bludgeoning Resistance

- [Barbarian Rage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/classes#Barbarian)
- Natural resistance by a [Monster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=&filter-resistance=1)

  - Non-module specific monsters include Awakened Trees, Swarm of Bats, Swarm of Insects, Swarm of poisonous snakes, Swarm of Kippers, Swarm of Rats, Swarm of Ravens, Treant, Wood woad.
- [Stoneskin spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/stoneskin) (non-magical only)

### [Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/768499211675369476) supports this logic:

> Rage gives you resistance to bludgeoning damage. If you take bludgeoning damage from a fall, you resist it

Comment: [Immunity to bludgeoning damage doesn't render a creature immune to damage from falls.](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/08/31/immunity-to-bludgeoning-does-take-damage-from-falling/) Similarly, why would resistance to bludgeoning damage reduce the damage from falls?

Comment: @HeyICanChan that ruling talks about a creature with immunity to bludge. damage **from weapons**. Since the floor isn't a weapon that is why they still take damage. I don't see any way that negates the answer here.

Comment: In fact, this ruling directly confirms this answer: "[Rage gives you resistance to bludgeoning damage. If you take bludgeoning damage from a fall, you resist it.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/768499211675369476)"

Comment: @Rubiksmoose  So it is! I'm on board! Then if the land spot's in lava, covered in punji sticks, or surrounded by scything blades, all bets are off? (I mean, it seems overly broad to rule that *falling* damage is *always* bludgeoning damage, when it's *landing* damage that should matter!)

Comment: @HeyICanChan a devious DM might actually rule that one would take fall damage (resisted) and punji stick damage in a case like that. But I can see that going multiple ways.

Comment: This answer should make the point that resistance or immunity to bludgeoning *weapon* damage does not help with falling.  That's non-obvious, because where do you draw the line between getting hit with a huge club vs. falling into an object with much larger mass than yourself.  But apparently in D&D it's the intent that matters- if it's wielded as a weapon by anything, your resistance works.  [Are there creatures that are resistant/immune to falling damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123442)