# Can a Werewolf survive being burnt at the stake?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, immunities

[As this answer to another question points out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/140023/9552), the [MM errata](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/MM-Errata.pdf) replaces resistance/immunity to "non-magical weapons" with resistance/immunity to "non-magical attacks".

Does this mean that a werewolf can't be burnt or drowned?

Comment: There’s an unexplained link in your post. Could you [edit] to indicate what its purpose here is?

Comment: and kids, this is the reason you should not post when you are ill. Please delete this.

Comment: @András I know this isn't what comments are for, and this will probably get deleted quickly, but sorry to hear that you're ill.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## The Werewolf would still die

Werewolves aren't immune to all non-magical attacks, they are immune to "**slashing, piercing, and bludgeoning damage** from non-magical attacks" (*emphasis mine)*.

Being burned at the stake would deal fire damage, and fire is still quite effective. Suffocation does not rely on dealing HP damage to kill in the first place.

Comment: so he would survive a fall from 100 meters?

Comment: Fall damages by passes resistances, in the tomb of annihilation it states that a certain weretiger is scarednof heights due to it

Comment: According to Jeremy Crawford (Lead rules designer for 5E): "Falling isn't considered a weapon by the rules." (https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/857271446892036096). Werewolves can die from falls.

Comment: I stand corrected. Removing my previous (incorrect) comment.

Comment: Also, falling isn't an attack, so it will bypass the new (post errata) resistance/immunity too.

Comment: @Deceptecium And for the record, fall damage [doesn't bypass all resistances](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123442/are-there-creatures-that-are-resistant-immune-to-falling-damage/123444#123444), just most.

Comment: Just everything but not a demon lord got it

Comment: Pretty much just them for immunity. For resistance, there's swarms, Treants, Awakened Trees, and people under the effect of certain game features (e.g. raging barbarians).