# Is there any way to change falling damage to another damage type?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage-types, falling

The rules on "[Falling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#Falling)" state:

> [...] At the end of a fall, a creature takes 1d6 bludgeoning damage for every 10 feet it fell, to a maximum of 20d6...

When looking at the [*reverse gravity*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/reverse-gravity) spell I realized it states:

> [...] If some solid object (such as a ceiling) is encountered in this fall, falling objects and creatures strike it just as they would during a normal downward fall...

And then in this related question "[Do any damage resistances apply to Reverse Gravity?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120431)" it is shown that falling damage, even from this spell, is still just bludgeoning damage. Is there any way to change the type of damage that a fall inflicts?

Maybe some object explicitly has this property or there is a way to change *all* damage a creature takes to another type, which would thus include fall damage?

If this is possible, then certain creatures, like the [treant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/treant), would take more damage from falling so pushing them off a cliff or using *reverse gravity* on them would be more effective.

If a method is available to *both* PC's and Monsters, that would be ideal. But if there is a method only available to PC's and another method only available to Monsters that would work as well. If these should be separate questions, that would be alright.

The closest thing I've found is the Horizon Walker Ranger's Planar Warrior feature, though it only works on weapon attacks and so not fall damage; the feature states:

> [...] As a bonus action, choose one creature you can see within 30 feet of you. The next time you hit that creature on this turn with a weapon attack, all damage dealt by the attack becomes force damage, [...]

Comment: I don't see a reason to ask separate questions. Any effect that does this is likely to apply to creatures anyway. I think the two questions would be too similar.

Answer (score 4):

## No

There are *lots* of ways to *add* additional non-bludgeoning damage to a fall -- a spiked pit at the bottom, for example, can add piercing and poison damage.  There are no ways, however, to convert bludgeoning, piercing, or slashing damage into anything else, just ways to add other stuff to it.  [The content on this related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102573/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-damage-type-being-dealt-by-a-weapon) supports that there are no ways of doing this for weapons, but there also aren't any ways of doing this to falling damage.

Comment: The linked answer is incorrect. For example, the Horizon Walker's Planar Warrior feature completely converts and attack to psychic type damage. Well, it's not incorrect for the specific situation of being a level 20 Barbarian, but there *are* ways to change an attack's damage type

Comment: @Medix2 The answer isn't linked, just the question - but I also don't think I disagree that the question is entirely about LEvel 20 Barbs. I think your edit was good.

Comment: Possibly useful link: [rules for falling in a pit of spikes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/running-the-game#SampleTraps).